# Why was this question on T Flip-Flops closed? Can we reopen it?

Tags: discussion

[T-flip-flop without using a clock](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/135424/238188) - This is a perfectly reasonable question in my opinion, and there is also a datasheet from Analog Devices of a T Flip-Flop that does not use a separate clock, that is, the input is the clock. The accepted answer is correct, but I don't think the question should have been closed. Also it seems to me that people did not *understand* the question, so they closed it.
Datasheet: https://www.digikey.be/htmldatasheets/production/1228052/0/0/1/hmc749lc3c.html

Comment: Is that the TFlipflop the OP is using?

Comment: @VoltageSpike, not exactly since the datasheet T Flip-Flop has a reset. But the concept is the same.

Comment: @VoltageSpike this answer has the same T Flip-Flop that the OP is using: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/540527/238188

Comment: The datasheet says it's an RF t flip-flop in IC which is vastly different than an HDL flip-flop or a flip-flop in a different package. You can't add a clock to an RF flip-flop, if it doesn't have one already

Comment: @VoltageSpike sorry I did not understand what you mean, but I am very interested to learn more, can you direct me to some resource for this?

Comment: There is no flip flop listed in this post or the comments (that I could find anyway, so the one that is listed in this post is incorrect): https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/135424/238188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a meta post to ask for reopening is improper, please use the voting system for that (when you get enough rep). The moderation ques allow people to vote on these questions.

The question is off topic and should remain closed because

1. the provided no context as to how they where creating the flip flop
2. they used an 'is it possible' question, (in which case the answer would probably be 'yes' or 'no'). *Specific questions* should be used when asking because they communicate exactly what the user wants to know instead of us having to ask in the comments.
3. the question is very short, short questions rarely provide an adequate enough description to allow a user to answer the question.
4. the question is 7 years old and already has an answer

If you do see a question that was closed then help the user edit thier question to make it on topic, after this process is done you could post a comment indicating that the post should be reopened or use a moderator flag and we could look at it

The post indicates that it was closed and five people voted on it.

Comment: I have not downvoted this, but I disagree a little. First of all, the question seems fine to me as it is, and does not require an edit. Or else I would have edited it. Also the user has confirmed their requirements in their comments.

Comment: If it has an answer does that mean it can closed? What does your 4th point mean? It does not look good to see valid questions closed.

Comment: It isn't a valid question, it is off topic. Furthermore, the OP got thier answer and checked the box, so additional answers probably aren't going to help the OP. At that point it's probably not meaningful to have more answers. And the OP hasn't been here for a while.

Comment: Okay I agree with you.

Comment: But that post is definitely useful. Won't it get deleted at some point of time if it is closed?

Comment: No, but it can be voted on for deletion, it takes 5 votes. It is rare for questions to get deleted like this and when they do they usually have multiple downvotes (like more than 4). Closing means it's not accepting new answers (all this info is found in the help center)

Comment: Discussing close reasons on meta is a perfectly reasonable thing.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I totally agree, but I would recommend doing this after you've read up on how the site works. This is the third time the OP has done this, I feel like these posts could have been avoided had the OP done prior research. If you do feel that a question has been closed wrongly, then their should also be supporting evidence as to why it should be reopened other than 'I think it should be reopened'. A better way might be 'I think it should be reopened because it is on topic for X reason' or 'This question is on topic, why was it closed?'

Comment: We tend to not moderate our meta to the extent we moderate the main page.  I've seen questions screened to a level they have not before, including moderator closes.  It just doesn't feel necessary

Comment: Moderator closes on the meta? Do explain